# How can I disable the touchpad while typing?

Tags: lenovo, radeon, 19.10, amd-processor

When typing text in LibreOffice or email, the cursor in my [Lenovo Flex 14 81ss AMD laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-flex-series/Lenovo-IdeaPad-FLEX-14API/p/88IP8FX1273) jumps around and causes chunks text to be moved arou the result, it's maddening.nd my document. Or sometimes it just gets deleted, or highlighted.

See what I mean?

Is there any setting in 19.10 that will fix this problem? This did not happen in 19.04

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101097/discussion-on-question-by-paul-ciosek-how-can-i-disable-the-touchpad-while-typin).

Comment: Any thoughts on this one?